# Recompile java classes without restarting jetty

Tags: maven-jetty-plugin

I am using the maven jetty plugin and starting the server from the console using:

mvn jetty:run

Is it possible to make jetty recompile my java classes whenever i change them in the file system?

It's kind of annoying to stop jetty, do mvn clean install and start jetty back again.

Answer (score 0):

Fernando,

The best way to use this plugin is in conjunction with your IDE, which will normally do class recompiles in the background. If you configure your plugin with a non-zero <scanIntervalSeconds> parameter, the plugin will notice changed files and do an automatic redeploy.

Jan

Comment: Thank you Jan, i will try this, however i had some issues with the Maven Plugin for Eclipse that didn't allow me to run jetty from within the IDE, that's why i moved to the console. These issues were related to not being able to do an Update Project because of errors that i couldn't resolve, even spending several hours on them.